# ArcGIS 10.1.1 libGLMapCore.so

Tags: android, arcgis, esri

Just upgraded my app to ArcGIS release 10.1.1 for Android, and started getting a runtime error.  If I add the libGLMapCore.so file to the projects libs->armeabi directory the problem goes away and the program runs fine.

This file is not in the ArgGIS samples HelloWorld, so I'm wondering why my project needs it. If anyone could help me figure this out, I'd be grateful.  (FYI - I tried to copy the libs folder from the ESRI example, but it didn't help.)  Below is a stack trace I get without the libGLMapCore.so file.

```
05-30 12:53:42.117: E/Trace(1738): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
05-30 12:53:42.507: W/dalvikvm(1738): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown  while initializing Lcom/esri/android/map/MapSurface;
05-30 12:53:42.507: D/AndroidRuntime(1738): Shutting down VM
05-30 12:53:42.507: W/dalvikvm(1738): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
05-30 12:53:42.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1738): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-30 12:53:42.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1738): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.baseops.airsuitability.main/com.baseops.airsuitability.main.AirfieldSuitabilityMain}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.esri.android.map.MapView
05-30 12:53:42.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
05-30 12:53:42.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-30 12:53:42.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-30 12:53:42.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-30 12:53:42.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-30 12:53:42.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-30 12:53:42.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-30 12:53:42.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-30 12:53:42.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-30 12:53:42.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-30 12:53:42.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-30 12:53:42.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-30 12:53:42.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1738): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.esri.android.map.MapView
05-30 12:53:42.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
05-30 12:53:42.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
05-30 12:53:42.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
05-30 12:53:42.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
05-30 12:53:42.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
05-30 12:53:42.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
05-30 12:53:42.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
05-30 12:53:42.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
05-30 12:53:42.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at com.baseops.airsuitability.main.AirfieldSuitabilityMain.onCreate(AirfieldSuitabilityMain.java:73)
05-30 12:53:42.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
05-30 12:53:42.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
05-30 12:53:42.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
05-30 12:53:42.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     ... 11 more
05-30 12:53:42.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1738): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-30 12:53:42.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
05-30 12:53:42.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
05-30 12:53:42.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
05-30 12:53:42.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     ... 22 more
05-30 12:53:42.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1738): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
05-30 12:53:42.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at com.esri.android.map.MapView.a(Unknown Source)
05-30 12:53:42.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at com.esri.android.map.MapView.<init>(Unknown Source)
05-30 12:53:42.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     ... 25 more
05-30 12:53:42.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1738): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load GLMapCore from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/com.baseops.airsuitability.main-1.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/com.baseops.airsuitability.main-1]: findLibrary returned null
05-30 12:53:42.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
05-30 12:53:42.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
05-30 12:53:42.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at com.esri.android.a.a.a(Unknown Source)
05-30 12:53:42.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at com.esri.android.map.MapSurface.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
05-30 12:53:42.527: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     ... 27 more
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is just a bug with ArcGIS when you use their plugin in a non-ArcGIS project.  Though, it's probably just an issue with Eclipse.  It doesn't copy over native libraries when you use a Java library...I'm not sure it would do that for any library.  But the MapSurface class is trying to use the native library and it's not there...so you **HAVE** to add it if Eclipse doesn't do it for you.

I was getting the same issue.  I found a post on the arcGIS forum that pointed to the fact that the ArcGIS native library .so files were missing from my project.  Like you seem to have done, I did the following to copy the native libraries to my project and now it links and creates a Map object:

- Create a new project with the SDK ArcGIS Project for Android wizard
- Copy the native libraries from the new project to your existing project. E.g. $//libs/armeabi(-v7a)/libruntimecore_java.so. Keep in mind this file name changed at v10.1.1.
- Right click your original project and select Properties
- Select Java Build Path > Order and Export tab
  Confirm that the ArcGIS for Android 10.1.1 classpath container is exported

Hope this helps.  Here's a link to the forum: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/87407-Error-inflating-class-com.esri.android.map.MapView?highlight=exception